# Using world Coordinates instead of latitude and longitude coordinates in google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I've to display some icons using google maps. I only have the world coordinates of this icons and I was wondering if there is a method in google maps API that I can use to put this icons.

Can you give me and example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

```
  var projection = new MercatorProjection();
  var worldCoordinate = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(chicago);
```

Maybe there is a reverse way. Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates